# Create a auth user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, devise

Im using `devise` in my rails application and everything is working fine, what Im trying to do now is to allow users to login to my app using their github account and create a profile.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_one :profile

  after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    self.create_profile
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    user = first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth['provider']
      user.uid = auth['uid']
      user.email = auth['info']['email']
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def github
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

I also ran the correct migration to add provider and uid column to the users table

```
rails g migration AddColumnsToUsers provider uid

def change
 add_column :users, :provider, :string
 add_column :users, :uid, :string
end
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :github, 'CLIENT_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'user:email'
```

When i create a user using `devise` it all works fine and users are created, but when i click sign in with github on my registration page it merges the devise account and github account together leaving me with one account, its not creating an account with user github credentials. Even if i try and login using 2 different github accounts, it still for some reason only uses the first github account.

problem is github user can login but they are not being created as users, using their github credentials, i need users to login and create a profile with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Devise's wiki it is said:

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
```

But I removed that `where` method. What happens now is you literally take THE FIRST record from the database and update it.

If no records are present in the database, a record will be created, but on subsequest registrations you will still fetch the first record and modify it. So i changed:

my User.rb to:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
```

and callbacks controller to:

```
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you give the credentials in **config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'], scope:"user:email,user:follow"
end
```

you can go through by [**Link**](https://www.natashatherobot.com/rails-omniauth-github-tutorial/)